# Write a rsa private key, stored in an environment variable to a JSON file without breaking the JSON string

Tags: json, bash, sed, environment-variables

What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to extract a RSA private key from an environment variable and write it into a JSON file. It should be the value of the key PRIVATE_KEY. The JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    "SOME_KEY": "123",
    "PRIVATE_KEY": "###PRIVATE_KEY###"
}
```

I then try to replace the '###PRIVATE_KEY###' with the actual private key using sed.
My code for replacing the placeholder with the actual key looks something like this:

```
sed -i "s~###PRIVATE_KEY###~$PRIVATE_KEY~" ~/path/to/my/file.json
```

The Problem:

When I write the private key to the json file using sed, it changes the \n characters in the string to actual newlines, resulting in breaking the JSON string. It then looks something like this:

```
{
    "SOME_KEY": "123",
    "PRIVATE_KEY": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQCK1nMX50Gkdt2Yf8qKFvt6zxK05NtIUbD8cyc7gp3NUGcphwvo
HDYQGsQqPPkHzUFbWwPoClHDZt9NUekKMKFY0EBDLsg2NwlIxNLm/Y/EWkUCQCyJ
...

1BpGWFir/XxEESQAzq5qlTTVMx3pR7ct/sDCZa9Ej1JNNctxe3cl2DOYFKdnqIRV
BF4OepzT1Av7l/XNi1kCQH2DvYEdBOQOBjt7VZuaBNX2Scz2LmypRFjF55s2lwdO
HFfVQDOMDWPDv+ZWrwI7+VosLj2Ax4aSV2xlkpZch1k=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"
}
```

Also I have double checked, the key is in the correct format until it gets written to the file with sed.

My Question:

How can I keep the \n characters when I write the private key to my json file? The whole key should fit on one line so it doesnt break the JSON.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jq` for this task.

```
jq --arg pk "$PRIVATE_KEY" '.PRIVATE_KEY = $pk' file.json
```

If you want to replace the existing file, like inplace, you can use this:

```
jq --arg pk "$PRIVATE_KEY" '.PRIVATE_KEY = $pk' file.json > file.json.tmp && mv file.json.tmp file.json
```

Above syntax means that the output of the `jq` command is saved to a temporary file, and (`&&`) if the this command wa successful, then the second command is executed, which is to move (`mv`) the temporary file to  `file.json`.

You can not directly write the output to the same file, because this will end with an empty file, as the file redirection is executed by the shell before the command starts.

Comment: What exactly does `file.json > file.json.tmp \
    && mv file.json.tmp file.json` do?

Comment: If you want to write the standard output of a command to a file, you follow this syntax: `command > file`. Then `&&` means `and` and the expression `command1 && command2` ensures that only if command1 finishes with no errors, then command2 will be executed. `mv file1 file2` is the move command. So `totally` this is modifing inplace the `file.jon`. (You can not do directly ` jq file.json > file.jon` because this will create an empty file, as the file redirection is executed by the shell before the command starts)

Comment: I have updated the answer with this explanation for your query.